# Where are the cookies being eaten?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firefox, cookies, cors

I have a backend and frontend running on different domains. The backend offers an API to the frontend and I'm in control of both. The backend sends a cookie to the frontend which I'm hopping the frontend is going to send back on further requests. **I don't need JavaScript to read the cookie, I just want it to be fetch from the backend and sent back to the backend**.

For the purpose of this experiment, the backend runs on http://api.localtest.me:8000 and the frontend on http://foo.lvh.me:3000. Both hostnames resolve to 127.0.0.1 as I'm running them on my own dev computer at the moment.

The server send these CORS headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.lvh.me:3000
```

to allow the client to talk to the server and receive cookies. The full request and response look like this:

```
curl.exe -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Origin: http://foo.lvh.me:3000" -H "Referer: http://foo.lvh.me:3000" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" --verbose http://app.localtest.me:8000/api-v1/current-user/

*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to app.localtest.me (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /api-v1/current-user/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: app.localtest.me:8000
> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
> DNT: 1
> Origin: http://foo.lvh.me:3000
> Referer: http://foo.lvh.me:3000
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2019 09:45:37 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.1
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
< Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 2
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.lvh.me:3000
< Set-Cookie:  sessionid=v04omdilmwz13h1vcirdz8r8pd6r5awv; expires=Wed, 30 Jan 2019 09:45:37 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
<
{}* Connection #0 to host app.localtest.me left intact
```

The server is very clearly sending a `Set-Cookie`. Now when I do exactly the same within Chrome, this is what the request and responses look like:

[image]

Notice the lack of `Set-Cookie`. Where was that cookie eaten? I debugged the backend, step by step and I saw the Set-Cookie header being written to the stream that goes to the browser.

The front end uses axios with credentials:

```
axios.get("http://api.localtest.me:8000/api-v1/current-user/", {withCredentials: true}).then(response => { console.log(response) })
```

The request as in `response.request` seems to show `withCredentials` correctly set:

[image]

I replaced the call to axios with:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://api.localtest.me:8000/api-v1/current-user/', true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(null);
```

and the behavior is exactly the same. I change `withCredentials` to be `false` and the behavior remained the same as well. This seems to go against what [`withCredentials` is supposed to do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) (emphasis mine):

> The XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property is a Boolean that
>   **indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be
>   made using credentials such as cookies**, authorization headers or TLS
>   client certificates. Setting withCredentials has no effect on
>   same-site requests.

In Firefox things are a bit different. It shows the cookie sent from the server, but doesn't send it back (in the picture, that's not the first request, so, the cookie sent should be the same):

[image]

I re-confirmed these were the headers both in the request and response by using Fiddler:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here?

I tried removing `SameSite: lax` from the cookie and the behavior was the same.

For clarification, none of these were the first request, there were previous requests that should have set the cookie. Here you can see three requests one after the other:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In the frontend JavaScript code that’s making the request, have you ensured the credentials mode is getting set to 'include'? https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode That is, if your frontend code is making the request with the fetch method, you’re setting credentials: 'include' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included. Or if you’re using XHR, you’ve set the 'withCredentials' property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: yes I have. Would this affect whether the server is sending back the cookie? If so, how?

Comment: Yeah setting the credentials mode to 'include' in the request wouldn’t directly affect whether the server sent back the cookie; instead it’s only affect whether cookies or other credentials were included in the request sent to the server — but depending on what the particular server behavior is, it’s imaginable that the absence of cookies/credentials in the request might affect whether the server sends back a cookie in the response.

Comment: I just read your edits/updates that seem to indicate you’re trying to access the Set-Cookie response header from your frontend JavaScript code. The fact that doesn’t work is intended behavior, by design; per-spec, browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the Set-Cookie response header. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name where Set-Cookie is defined as a “forbidden response-header name”

Comment: @sideshowbarker: no, I'm not trying to access it from JavaScript, I'm just hopping it'd be sent back to the server in subsequent requests. I found the solution, which is in an answer to this question and it's less interesting and more infuriating than expected.

Comment: Ah, OK — glad you found a solution. (/me smiles at *“less interesting and more infuriating than expected”*…)

Comment: Actually, I didn't. It was just a case of foo.lvh.me and api.lvh.me being the same domain.

Comment: I completely re-wrote the question to be more clear about the symptoms I'm seeing. As far as I can see, Chrome might somehow be eating the cookies.

Comment: Are you expecting the browser will take the Set-Cookie value of the response from domain api.localtest.me to use it to actually set a cookie in the browser’s cookie store for the completely different domain foo.lvh.me? Since cookies are domain-scoped, it’s expected (required) per-spec and per the web security model that browsers won’t use a cookie in a response from domain A to set a cookie for domain B, right?

Comment: @sideshowbarker: no, all I want is the cookie from `api.localtest.me` to go back to `api.localtest.me`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186776/discussion-between-pupeno-and-sideshowbarker).

Comment: Here is a related Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617198